# Why am I receiving "TypeError: non-boolean (DataArrays.NAtype) used in boolean context"?

Tags: julia

I am wondering if anybody can explain to me what this error means, and possibly how to resolve it. I can include the whole program of code if necessary, but here is the error message I am receiving, as well as the part of the program causing it.

```
    for i =1:num_hitters
    if hitters[i,:Position] == "OF"
outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(1,1))
catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(0,1))
firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(0,1))
thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(0,1))
shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(0,1))
    elseif hitters[i,:Position] == "C"
        outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(0,1))
            catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(1,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
            secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(0,1))
            thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(0,1))
            shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(0,1))
    elseif hitters[i,:Position] == "1B"
        outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(0,1))
            catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(0,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(1,1))
            secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(0,1))
            thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(0,1))
            shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(0,1))
elseif hitters[i,:Position] == "2B"
        outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(0,1))
            catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(0,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
            secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(1,1))
            thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(0,1))
            shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(0,1))
elseif hitters[i,:Position] == "3B"
        outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(0,1))
            catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(0,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
            secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(0,1))
            thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(1,1))
            shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(0,1))
elseif hitters[i,:Position] == "SS"
        outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(0,1))
            catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(0,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
            secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(0,1))
            thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(0,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
            shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(1,1))
    else
        outfield=vcat(outfield,fill(0,1))
            catchers=vcat(catchers,fill(0,1))
        firstbase=vcat(firstbase,fill(0,1))
        secondbase=vcat(secondbase,fill(0,1))
            thirdbase=vcat(thirdbase,fill(0,1))
            shortstop=vcat(shortstop,fill(1,1))
      end
    end
```

Here is the error

```
    TypeError: non-boolean (DataArrays.NAtype) used in boolean context
 in create_lineups at C:\Users\Jake\Documents\GitHub\MLB_DFS_ALGO.jl:176
 in include_string at loading.jl:288
 in eval at C:\Users\Jake\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\Atom.jl:3
 [inlined code] from C:\Users\Jake\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:39
 in anonymous at C:\Users\Jake\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:108
 in withpath at C:\Users\Jake\.julia\v0.4\Requires\src\require.jl:37
 in withpath at C:\Users\Jake\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:53
 [inlined code] from C:\Users\Jake\.julia\v0.4\Atom\src\eval.jl:107
 in anonymous at task.jl:58
```

If anybody can explain why this is happening, or point to one of my stupid errors I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your DataFrame contains at least one NA.  You need to either make sure the data contains no missing values or explicitly handle them before attempting to compare them with `==`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, was not sure if I needed to delete the empty rows in the DataFrame or not, but now I know I do.